# Can't connect to localhost MySQL with PHPUnit in PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

I've set up a local MySQL database and some unit testing tables, and while PHP itself can connect to the localhost server just fine, when I try to run PHPUnit unit tests in the JetBrains PhpStorm IDE, I run into this error when using the PDO connection:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (2002)

As well as:

> Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (3D000)

My code (which works outside PHPUnit tests) is:

```
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
// ...set PDO settings
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

If I replace it with 127.0.0.1, it still doesn't work. The strange thing is, the line where I create and configure the PDO connection object doesn't throw any exceptions. It's only when I try to do anything on the connection like a SELECT that these errors are thrown.

I'm running OS X 10.9, no firewall, latest PhpStorm, PHPUnit, MySQL etc. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How did you prove `[...]while PHP itself can connect to the localhost server just fine[...]`? Did you test your code in the browser, and run the Unit tests from command line?

Comment: @t.niese the site running on the same local DB works, and so does Sequel Pro connecting directly to the DB without going through PHP. I will try running phpunit from the command line (outside PhpStorm) to see if it's not PhpStorm.

Comment: I ask the question, because often _php_fpm_, the _php apache module_, and the _php cli_ use different php.ini files. As of that a script that might work well in the server environment _php_fpm_/_php apache module_  might fail in in _cli_  or the other way round. Additionally you should check if mysql is actually listening on a _port_ or if it is only listening on a _file socket_.

Comment: @t.niese I've done some tinkering and confirmed that I can successfully connect to it on 127.0.0.1:3306 but still no connection when running unit tests with PHPUnit/Storm :-(

Comment: What does your `$dsn` look like?